# Access public variable in uitableviewcell subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change the value of a `UILabel` when someone taps on it.

The values to which I want to change it to, are defined in the `ViewController` itself.

Right now, I'm working with this code:

```
- (void)tapOnBalance {
  TimelineViewController *timelineVC = [[TimelineViewController alloc]init];
  if(timelineVC.oldBalance && timelineVC.newBalance){
  NSTimeInterval duration = 0.5f;
  [UIView transitionWithView:self.amountLabel
                    duration:duration
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                  animations:^{
                    self.amountLabel.text = timelineVC.newBalance;    
                  } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                      self.amountLabel.text = timelineVC.oldBalance;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"finished");
                   }];
  }];
  }
}
```

However, because i'm probably initializing the `TimelineViewController` as a new insance, all the initial values are nil, so the codeblock inside the `if/else` statement never runs.

How do I access those public values without creating a new instance of the `TimelineViewController`?

Comment: Really bad idea. A cell should not have any knowledge of any view controller. Your cell class should define a protocol and have a delegate property. Then your view controller can be the cell's delegate. Then the cell can ask its delegate to provide an updated value when needed. This allows your cell to work without any specific knowledge of where it's getting its data from.

Comment: @rmaddy seems legit, but it's a lot more work for the same task. What evil might I cause when I'm doing it this way?

Comment: It's too much coupling. Your cell requires too much knowledge about a specific view controller and worse, how it's data is setup. What happens if you end up needing the same kind of table cell in a 2nd view controller? Sure, it's quick and easy now to have the cell directly access data from a specific view controller, but long term you will regret it. Your code will require more work later on as things change. Plus, It goes completely against good MVC design.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you create a new instance of `TimelineViewController` each time `tapOnBalance` is called.

I am not sure how your architecture is like, but the solution that comes to mind is to create a property for the `TimelineViewController` inside the view controller that implements `tapOnBalance`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TimelineViewController *timelineVC;
```

in your file header or a private interface.
Then initialize that once inside `viewDidLoad` and access it with `self.timelineVC`.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't update the newBalance and oldBalance once the TimelineViewController is initialized

Comment: Where and how do you set those?